# Is there any way to catch fatal signal 11 of webview while playing html-5 video on Android

Tags: android, multithreading, exception, webview, html5-video

While playing a corrupt html-5 video on Android webview, my application crashed. When I checked the logs, I found that it crashed due to a fatal signal 11. I understand that the video is corrupt due to which webview couldn't render and crashed, but is there any way by which we can catch that exception and prevent the app from crashing.

I tried catching it at the application level as well by using Thread.uncaughtExceptionHandler but this method never gets called for this particular exception.

Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: Please post the stacktrace.

Comment: There is no stacktrace for this. There is just one line - 06-27 18:14:47.526: A/libc(32659): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 592 (Thread-1045)

Comment: There is a stacktrace.  It will be a C core dump, but it should either be in the full logcat or in the traces file.  The particular crash you had means someone passed a null pointer into libc.  For more info you'd need to give us the full C stack trace.